# No subject alternative DNS name matching ex.ample.com found

Tags: java, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

For my application running at ex.ample.com I have the following certificate from StartSSL/StartCom:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 163069 (0x27cfd)
        Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=IL, O=StartCom Ltd., OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing, CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov 27 21:26:01 2010 GMT
            Not After : Nov 29 15:32:05 2011 GMT
        Subject: description=303703-Sv1xMdnmzg6garMt, C=NL, O=Persona Not Validated, OU=StartCom Free Certificate Member, CN=ex.ample.com/emailAddress=postmaster@ex.ample.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus (2048 bit):
                    ....
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Key Agreement
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                31:68:B2:7B:A2:7C:79:54:B7:3E:66:FD:12:04:18:FC:FB:9B:34:64
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:EB:42:34:D0:98:B0:AB:9F:F4:1B:6B:08:F7:CC:64:2E:EF:0E:2C:45

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:ex.ample.com, DNS:ample.com
            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.23223.1.2.2
                  CPS: http://www.startssl.com/policy.pdf
                  CPS: http://www.startssl.com/intermediate.pdf
                  User Notice:
                    Organization: StartCom Ltd.
                    Number: 1
                    Explicit Text: Limited Liability, see section *Legal Limitations* of the StartCom Certification Authority Policy available at http://www.startssl.com/policy.pdf

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 
                URI:http://www.startssl.com/crt1-crl.crl
                URI:http://crl.startssl.com/crt1-crl.crl

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.startssl.com/sub/class1/server/ca
                CA Issuers - URI:http://www.startssl.com/certs/sub.class1.server.ca.crt

            X509v3 Issuer Alternative Name: 
                URI:http://www.startssl.com/
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        .....
```

I have this certificate installed correctly. It works when I access the app with Firefox.
When I use Java's `HttpURLConnection` to retrieve a page from it though, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching ex.ample.com found.
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:208)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:94)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:285)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:271)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1012)
    ... 14 more
```

I don't understand why this happens. `ex.ample.com` is the Common Name (CN) in the cert and is also listed in the SANs.
I've imported StarSLL's certificates in my truststore, so that's not the problem here.

Comment: what is the URL? By the way, the CN does *not* contain a valid hostname, but the subject alternative name does.

Comment: The URL is simply https://ex.ample.com/foo/bar. Obviously that's a sample, not the real URL, but the URL I access from Java works fine in a normal browser.

Comment: I understand it is a sample. In looking at the Java source code for those classes, it appears that something about your sample is not quite faithful to the real URL/certificate you used. Or I could have missed something, HostnameChecker is a complex class.

Comment: Perhaps a bit late, but is it possible that your server was set up using Server Name Indication (SNI), thereby presenting a different cert depending on the requested host name? Java 6 (at the time) did not support SNI (so it could have fallen back to whatever other cert was configured).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still looking for answer. Probably not!

The issue here is the DNS entry in your certificate is not matching with the server/host name you are providing in the application. Your code have a hostname verification somewhere. Either remove that bit of code or change the hostname you are providing to the DNS name in the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

We faced this issue recently, it was a nightmare because we were able to reproduce it only in Production servers, were access to debug is near to zero. The rest of environments were just working fine. Our stack was JDK 1.8.x+, JBoss EAP 7+, Java Spring Boot app and Okta as identity provider (the SSL handshake was failing when recovering the well-known configuration from Okta, where okta is available in AWS Cloud - virtual servers).

Finally, we discover that (no one knows why) the JBoss EAP application server that we were using it was having an additional JVM System Property:

**jsse.enableSNIExtension = false**

This was preventing to establish TLS connection and we were able to reproduce the issue by adding that same system property/value in other environments. So the solution was simple to **remove that undesired property and value**.

As per Java Security Doc, this property is set by default to true for Java 7+ (refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#InstallationAndCustomization)

> - jsse.enableSNIExtension system property. Server Name Indication (SNI) is a TLS extension, defined in RFC 4366. It enables TLS connections to virtual servers, in which multiple servers for different network names are hosted at a single underlying network address.
>   Some very old SSL/TLS vendors may not be able handle SSL/TLS extensions. In this case, set this property to false to disable the SNI extension.